# How to give both the conference year and the publication year when citing articles in conference proceedings?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

In APA style, to cite a conference paper, we would use the format (according to https://www.easybib.com/guides/citation-guides/apa-format/how-to-cite-conference-paper-apa/):

**Last name, FM. (Year published). Title of Paper or Proceedings, Title of Conference, Location, Date. Place of publication: Publisher.**

The conference paper I am trying to cite is from a conference that occurred in 1989 and the proceedings of which were published in 2001. I would thus have:

**Last name, FM. 2001. Title of Paper or Proceedings, Title of Conference, Maghnia, 1989. Algiers: CNRPAH.**

How do I do this in LaTeX? It seems that the full template for @inproceedings is (from https://www.bibtex.com/t/template-inproceedings/):

```
@InProceedings{citekey,

  author       = "",
  title        = "",
  booktitle    = "",
  year         = "",
  editor       = "",
  volume       = "",
  number       = "",
  series       = "",
  pages        = "",
  month        = "",
  address      = "",
  organization = "",
  publisher    = "",
  note         = "",
  annote       = ""
}
```

There's only one field for the year in here. How do I include both years? I use biber.

Comment: A quick workaround would be to just add any required information to a field that is available, for example `booktitle = {Title of Conference, Maghnia, 1989}`. That is not very suitable for use with other styles where the presence/order/formatiing of the subparts is different, but for finalizing a document it may be an easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't trust third-party websites for details of APA references. The final decision can only be made if you consult the APA manual, but the only open-access online resource I would trust is the APA style webpage https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples.

The APA website distinguishes conference presentation and proceeding references. Conference presentation references are of the form your website suggested (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/conference-presentation-references), but references to conference proceedings follow the normal `@article`/`@incollection` approach (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/conference-proceeding-references). In particular in the latter case all entries mention only one date: the date of publication.

Since you seem to want to refer to a conference paper, the only date that should appear is the publication date.

If you insist on having the date of the conference mentioned as well, most `biblatex` styles are aware of an `eventdate` field for `@inproceedings`. Alternatively, many `biblatex` styles also support `titleaddon` for generic additional information you might want to add after the title. (Of course all this assumes the year of the conference is not naturally part of the `title` anyway.)

Comment: That should probably be `eventdate`, with `t`?

Comment: @Marijn Ugh. Of course. Thanks for catching that. Should be fixed now.